# Tag popup layout is broken for localized sites

Tags: bug, tags, design, localization, popups

Tag popup layout is broken on certain tags for localized sites. For instance:

[c++ tag on Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B):

> [image: c++-ru]

[php tag on Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php):

> [image: php-pt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the tag popup design has been completely reworked this is not an issue anymore.

Current views (in dark theme):

> [image: C++ ruSO]

> [image: php ptSO]